# API throwing 503 service unavailable error occasionally and not continuously

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ec2, aws-api-gateway, http-status-code-503

I am getting error with status code **503 - Service Unavailable** in my **OPTIONS** request to API Gateway in AWS **(Screenshot attached below)**

[image: As you can see the OPTIONS request is failing]

**Our Tech Stack:**

1. API Gateway to route requests to proper docker container(s) residing inside EC2 instance running on docker-compose.
2. Have enabled VPC peering to connect our application hosted inside the EC2 instance with MongoDB Atlas.

I had a word with the solutions architect at AWS and he said that I've configured the CORS correctly for the API Gateway and it's not a CORS issue. He said that it is an issue on my application hosted on EC2 instance.

My application is hosted in a **microservices** fashion on **docker-compose** and consists of **3 microservices**. And I am facing this **status 503 - Service Unavailable** error only on 1 of my microservices out of the 3. The other two microservices are working perfectly fine without any issues.

I am able to see only those requests that had **status 200 - OK** inside my docker container logs and not those logs which encountered a **status 503 - Service Unavailable** error.

**My API Gateway CORS configuration is as follows:**

[image: API Gateway CORS Config]

**Also, attaching the log generated by the API gateway in Cloudwatch:**

```
{
    "requestId": "P1Zp3iC0BcwEJBA=",
    "ip": "<SOME IP>",
    "requestTime": "31/Mar/2022:05:31:17 +0000",
    "httpMethod": "OPTIONS",
    "routeKey": "ANY /master/{proxy+}",
    "status": "503",
    "protocol": "HTTP/1.1",
    "responseLength": "33",
    "Request_ID": "-",
    "resourcePath": "-"
}
```

I am not able to figure out the root cause as to why this error is popping up occasionally and not continuously as I have mentioned in the title of this question.

Comment: You need to investigate why your application is returning 503s, if you aren't logging application requests, now is the time.

Comment: Okay, do you recommend any specific tool for the same?
Right now I am using Cloudwatch logs to visualize the logs of my EC2 instance

Comment: CW logs is great, but you need to make sure you are actually logging what you need to log. This isn't a matter of using a tool, this is a matter of doing the right thing in the code at the right time. It is heavily dependent on the framework you already using.

Comment: I have found the issue I think. And, the issue is my gunicorn worker is timing out. Any recommendations as to how to mitigate from this issue?

Comment: Why is it timing out?